# How to transition CSS display in a ScrollDown show Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi everyone this is my problem:

I show a DIV tag when people scrollDown and I did something like this;

```
const list = document.getElementById("Ventana").classList;
if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
list.add("d-block");
} else {
list.remove("d-block");
}
```

At same time have my CSS class `cta-hide`, this class contains;

```
.cta-hide{
display: none;
opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 0.3s;
}
```

And this is my HTML element:

```
<div id="Ventana" class="sticky-bottom cta-hide global-bg-bluegrey">Stick to the bottom on viewports sized SM (small) or wider</div>
```

I have tried to change the opacity doing this;

```
const nodes = document.getElementsByClassName("cta-hide");
if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
nodes[i].style.opacity = 1;
}
list.add("d-block");
} else {
list.remove("d-block");
}
```

but it does not work :C animations don't works too

I need to show the div with the transition

Answer (score 0):

Well I did the next code:

1.- First I add the next classes:

```
.cta-hide{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

For to hide the element and this for the styles:

```
.cta-mob{
   background-color: green;
    color: white;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

and then add the classes to the DIV

```
    <div id="Ventana" class="cta-hide cta-mob" style="position: sticky;
  top: -1px;">Stick to the bottom on viewports sized SM (small) or wider</div>
```

on JS I do this:

```
const list = document.getElementById("Ventana").classList;

if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {
    list.remove("cta-hide");
} else {
    list.add("cta-hide");
}
```

And it works

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {

    const list = document.getElementById("Ventana").classList;

    if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 50) {

        list.remove("cta-hide");
    } else {
        list.add("cta-hide");
    }
}
```

```css
.cta-hide{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.cta-mob{
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:black; height:1000px">
<div id="Ventana" class="cta-hide cta-mob" style="position: sticky;
  top: -1px;">Stick to the bottom on viewports sized SM (small) or wider</div>
</div>
```